# Showing divisibility by 2304

Tags: number-theory

Show that, for each integer $n \geq 1$, the number $49^n-2352n-1$ is divisible by 2304.

Proof by induction:

**Basic Step:** Let n=1. $49-2352-1=-2304$ which 2304 divides -2304.

**Assume that the number above is divisible by 2304 for the n case.**

We need to show that this is true for the n+1 case.

$\frac{49^{n+1}-2352(n+1)-1}{2304}=\frac{49^n49-2352n-1-2352}{2304}=\frac{49^n-2353n-1}{2304}+\frac{49^n48-2352}{2304}$

The first fraction is an integer because of our hypothesis. Now, we need to show that the second fraction is also an integer.

$\frac{49^n48-2352}{2304}=\frac{49^n48-48*49}{48^2}=\frac{49^n-49}{48}$

And here is where I am stuck . Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that $49^n-49\equiv 0\mod 48$. When working modulo $48$, this simplifies to 
$$ 49^n-49\equiv 1^n-1\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\mod 48$$So we know that $49^n-49$ is divisible by $48$, thus the fraction you gave is an integer.

Comment: I really like this answer! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show by induction that $49^{n} - 49$ is always divisible by $48$. Note that

$$49^{n+1}-49 = 49(49^{n}-1) = 49(49^{n} - 49 + 49 - 1)$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $2304 = 48^2$ and $2352 = 2304+48$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

After you prove it for $\;n=1\;$ the inductive step is:

$$49^{n+1}-2352(n+1)-1=49\cdot 49^n-2352n-2352-1=$$

$$=49(49^n-2352n-1)+(48n-1)2352+48$$

But in fact

$$(48n-1)2352+48=48\left[1+49(48n-1)\right]=\underbrace{48}_{=2^4\cdot3}\left[3\cdot 2^4\cdot 7^3n-3\cdot 2^4\right]=$$

$$=2^83^2\left[7^3n-1\right]
$$

and we're done, since $\;2304=2^83^2\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Without induction,

As $48^2=2304,$ $$49^n=(1+48)^n=1+48n+48^2(\cdots)\equiv1+48n\pmod{48^2}$$

Now, $$48\equiv48+2304\pmod{2304}\equiv2352\implies48n\equiv2352n\pmod{2304}$$